# Why isn't this exponential function showing in Maple using implicitplot3d?

Tags: maple

Trying to graph the following function:

```
implicitplot3d(100*exp(-20.4+1.482*x+.399*y+.498*z)/(1+exp(-20.4+1.482*x+.399*y+.498*z)), x = 0 .. 40, y = 0 .. 40, z = 0 .. 15)
```

I don't see anything wrong with the syntax, and Maple does not produce an error. Simply produces a 3D region with nothing in it.

I did input `with(plots):`

Comment: In `?implicitplot3d` for the first argument: *"expr
-
**equation** containing expressions in x, y, and z"*

Comment: To followup on Therkel's comment: when the first argument `expr` passed to implicitplot3d is just an expression and not an equation (nb. an equation contains `=`) then the command interprets it as meaning `expr=0`. Your expression is strictly positive for real x,y and z. Did you forget to add some constant to it? Eg, `exp(...)/(1+exp(...)) - 91.3` say?

Comment: Yup made it an equation and it worked. Thank you